# Dialog layout weights

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a very simple `LinearLayout` for a Dialog. But my layout weights do not take any effect. The `Space` elements remain invisible. I think I have set the `height` attributes of all elements in the correct way, so I can't come up with any other solution. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="7"
tools:context=".MenuDialog">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/textSkip"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSkip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/btnSkip" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/textEnd"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEnd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/btnEnd" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/btnBack" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code for inflating the layout:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    MenuDialog menuDialog = MenuDialog.newInstance();
    menuDialog.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achive? From documentation: "Space is a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts." I think     Space is suppose to be invisible

Comment: @TonyDanilov yes you are right. But the Space should occupy the space corresponding to the weight it was assigned.

Comment: Have you tested it with View widget instead of Space?? For your purposes the View widget should be enough (Space extends it)

Comment: @giroxiii Good idea. However, it makes the Dialog stretch to maximum size and contain only a big white space. UI elements are gone

Comment: @PKlumpp If you just replace the word Space for View (keeping the properties), that View should not be more than that a transparent space with the given weight.

Comment: @giroxiii I did exactly that.

Comment: @PKlumpp Weird, there must be something else... I quickly tested it and it worked. When you preview the layout in Android Studio, do you see it as you want? I mean, the issue happens only when you inflate it within a Dialog or always? Can you test to inflate it in a common view (Fragment/Activity)??

Comment: @giroxiii Only happens within a Dialog. That is suspicious

Comment: @PKlumpp Then it would be useful to have the code where you instantiate de Dialog and inflate the layout

Comment: @giroxiii I edited my question

Comment: @PKlumpp the key is within the MenuDialog class, share it please

Answer (score 0):

[Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space) is a invisible View, it is just used to create gaps between View and ViewGroup.

If you want to show something in that gap than you can replace [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space) with [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View).